# External webcam not detected

Tags: 13.10, webcam

I have a Lubuntu 13.10 installed on a HP Pavillon dv6000.
I just bought a new webcam, Make is Growing, model is "Impala PC Camera".
I want to use it with skype, but it is not detected at all. Nor it is in cheese.
Any help would be appreciated.

The following command gave those results:

```
lsmod |grep uvcvideo 

uvcvideo               71309  0  
videobuf2_vmalloc      13048  1 uvcvideo   
videobuf2_core         39125  1 uvcvideo   
videodev              107508  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core

lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub     
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub   
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub   
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:048e Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Optical Mouse   
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub   
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure weather it will work or not but may be you can try this script

1st of all your terminal should give you

```
$ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0
```

where video0 is your current webcam

then

```
sudo apt-get install fswebcam
```

then

```
fswebcam --device /dev/video0 --input 0 --resolution 352x288 --save /var/www/public/webcam/webcam.jpg --skip 20 -v
```

or

```
fswebcam -r 640x480 -d /dev/video0 -v ./webcam.jpg
```

or simply use software center and install

Darktable Photo Workflow Software

Found one and not anywhere, inside Software Center. Darktable:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTm0I.png]

[image]

Comment: type lsusb and give us the device id it should help.